# why am i getting index out of range error here please explain

Tags: python, string

```
    new_str=input()
    for j in range(len(new_str)):
        for k in range(j+1,len(new_str)):
            if new_str[j]==new_str[k]:
                new_str=new_str[:k]+new_str[k+1:]
    print(new_str)
```

Here I am trying to remove the repeated letters of a string and print it but I am getting the error  of string index out of range. I am not understanding why. Can anyone explain me why?
the error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/submission/20230712/16/14/hackerrank-253aaa8879419e0d201489ccb06df6d8/code/Solution.py", line 17, in 
merge_the_tools(string, k)
File "/tmp/submission/20230712/16/14/hackerrank-253aaa8879419e0d201489ccb06df6d8/code/Solution.py", line 7, in merge_the_tools
if new_str[j]==new_str[k]:
~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: For starters, what are the values of j and k when it fails (and new_str and n for that matter too). Then walk through the code and see how it can get there.

Comment: While fixing this could be good from an academic perspective, you really should use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the string length while iterating over the loop, as Taha's answer told, which is causing the `IndexError`. In this case, it's better to use a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop, which runs based on the initial length of the string.

Here's the updated code.

```
new_str=input()

left = 0
while left < len(new_str)-1:
    right = left + 1

    while right < len(new_str):
        if new_str[left] == new_str[right]:
            new_str = new_str[:right] + new_str[right+1:]

        right += 1

    left += 1

print(new_str)
```

`left` and `right` stand for your iterators `j` and `k` respectively here.

Output (Positive Case):

```
akka
ak
```

Output (Negative Case):

```
ghij
ghij
```